# R: Understanding the Differences Between Two Plots

Tags: r, 3d, plotly, data-visualization, simulation

I am using the R programming language. I am following this tutorial over here: https://plotly.com/r/3d-line-plots/

I copy and pasted the following code and successfully created this plot:

```
library(plotly)

data <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/_3d-line-plot.csv')

fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x1, y = ~y1, z = ~z1, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines',
        line = list(color = '#1f77b4', width = 1))
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(x = ~x2, y = ~y2, z = ~z2,
            line = list(color = 'rgb(44, 160, 44)', width = 1))
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(x = ~x3, y = ~y3, z = ~z3,
            line = list(color = 'bcbd22', width = 1))

fig
```

[image]

When you preview the data used to make this 3D graph, it looks like this:

```
> head(data)
           x1         y1        z1         x2         y2          z2
1 -0.01446036 -0.7007406 0.7132696 -0.5876227  0.2779929  -0.7598812
2  0.42072305 -4.2273350 3.1998977 -1.0323807 -0.4265484  -5.4042929
3  0.47195564 -3.3451935 2.0209429 -0.9554478 -3.3332747  -7.1266061
4 -1.59808508 -5.2404711 1.4572559  0.7305834 -2.8338860 -10.2886736
5 -1.16969290 -4.3295068 1.9317851  2.9333971 -1.0720493 -11.5012063
6  0.62887816 -1.7364294 3.2375436  4.2536182 -4.1168275 -13.0858438
          x3          y3         z3
1 -0.3666438  0.67189166 -0.6435324
2  1.4686770 -0.28710213  1.1944073
3  1.4915815  2.09425411  1.7574972
4  2.6986862 -0.04325033 -2.0862012
5  2.6568411  0.01913790 -3.1839338
6 -1.5095767 -2.69654294 -0.2990162
> str(data)
'data.frame':   1001 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ x1: num  -0.0145 0.4207 0.472 -1.5981 -1.1697 ...
 $ y1: num  -0.701 -4.227 -3.345 -5.24 -4.33 ...
 $ z1: num  0.713 3.2 2.021 1.457 1.932 ...
 $ x2: num  -0.588 -1.032 -0.955 0.731 2.933 ...
 $ y2: num  0.278 -0.427 -3.333 -2.834 -1.072 ...
 $ z2: num  -0.76 -5.4 -7.13 -10.29 -11.5 ...
 $ x3: num  -0.367 1.469 1.492 2.699 2.657 ...
 $ y3: num  0.6719 -0.2871 2.0943 -0.0433 0.0191 ...
 $ z3: num  -0.644 1.194 1.757 -2.086 -3.184 ...
```

Just as a learning exercise, I tried to create a similar dataset and run the same procedure:

```
x1 = rnorm(1000,10,10)
x2 = rnorm(1000,10,10)
x3 = rnorm(1000,10,10)
y1 = rnorm(1000,10,10)
y2 = rnorm(1000,10,10)
y3 = rnorm(1000,10,10)
z1 = rnorm(1000,10,10)
z2 = rnorm(1000,10,10)
z3 = rnorm(1000,10,10)
data = data.frame(x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3,z1,z2,z3)


fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x1, y = ~y1, z = ~z1, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines',
        line = list(color = '#1f77b4', width = 1))
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(x = ~x2, y = ~y2, z = ~z2,
            line = list(color = 'rgb(44, 160, 44)', width = 1))
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(x = ~x3, y = ~y3, z = ~z3,
            line = list(color = 'bcbd22', width = 1))

fig
```

But the graph that comes from this code looks completely different:

[image]

Can someone please help me understand why the two graphs are different and how can I modify the second graph so that it looks more like the first graph?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The problem is, you are mistaking random distribution for the random walk. The data you are trying to replicate is following a random walk.

To do so, let's make a function which generates a  random walk data like,

```
random_walk <- function(n,mean,sd) {

        out <- vector()
        initial <- rnorm(1,10,10)
        out[1] <- initial
        for(i in 2:n) {

        out[i] <- out[i-1] + rnorm(1,mean,sd)
                        }
        return(out)

    }
```

Now we can create our entire data set by using our function,

```
x1 <- random_walk(1000,0,1)
x2 <- random_walk(1000,0,1)
x3 <- random_walk(1000,0,1)

y1 <- random_walk(1000,0,1)
y2 <- random_walk(1000,0,1)
y3 <- random_walk(1000,0,1)

z1 <- random_walk(1000,0,1)
z2 <- random_walk(1000,0,1)
z3 <- random_walk(1000,0,1)


data_new = data.frame(x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3,z1,z2,z3)
```

Finally, we can plot it,

```
fig_new <- plot_ly(data_new, x = ~x1, y = ~y1, z = ~z1, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines',
            line = list(color = '#1f77b4', width = 1))
fig_new <- fig_new %>% add_trace(x = ~x2, y = ~y2, z = ~z2,
            line = list(color = 'rgb(44, 160, 44)', width = 1))
fig_new <- fig_new %>% add_trace(x = ~x3, y = ~y3, z = ~z3,
            line = list(color = 'bcbd22', width = 1))

fig_new
```

which gives,

[image]

Comment: You can do the random walk for each vector with `cumsum(rnorm(1000, 0, 10))`.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, you can save a bunch of typing by doing something like `library(tidyverse); data = paste0(rep(c("x","y","z"), each=3), 1:3) %>% 
  set_names() %>% map_df(~assign(.x, cumsum(rnorm(1000,0,10))))`

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Can you please explain why a random walk function must be defined for making this graph? Suppose i have real life observations (e.g. daily earnings of a financial company) and i want to plot this kind of graph. Is it still possible? Thank you!

Comment: There's no requirement to plot random walk data or any particular kind of data. It's just that the plot will look different depending on the structure of the data. In a random walk, the location of each new point is correlated with the previous points, so the 3D graph form "nice" paths that are each to visualize and understand. However, `rnorm(1000,10,10)` produces data that can jump anywhere from one point to the next, zig-zagging around and creating the solid ball of points that you found when you made your plot.

Comment: This might be easier to see in 1 dimension. Try running these lines of code a few times (the first line is just so that both plots will be drawn together): `par(mfrow=c(1,2));
plot(1:1000, rnorm(1000, 0, 10), type="l");
plot(1:1000, cumsum(rnorm(1000, 0, 10)), type="l")`. The first plot is like the random data you created. Note how the points jump up an down (within about 2 standard deviations of zero) from one point to the next, because each point is completely independent of the previous one. The second plot is a random walk, where each successive point is close to the previous one.

Comment: So, yes, you can plot your financial data (assuming you have three relevant dimensions to plot), but whether the graph will look "nice" or an uninterpretable mess depends on the structure of the data. Since financial data usually have correlations from day to day, you may find that the correlation structure results in relatively smooth paths through 3D space.

Comment: @eipi10 Oh yes. `cumsum()` is an easier alternative comparing to create a function.

Comment: @Nobb If you ok with the answer, please accept it to close the topic. Have a look a this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers